# Object is positioning through joints

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I didn't know how to best describe this problem in the title but Ill show you pictures to illustrate what I mean.

[image: This is the problem I am having]

[image: This is what I'm trying to do]

(1) Image 1 shows the problem I am having

(2) Image 2 shows what I am trying to achieve.

-- The problem --
As you can see i am trying to make the 3 blocks align with the exception of the spike, which extrudes out. When I set this up in corona it basically makes the images align by height.

Here is my spawn function:

```
function createBlock(event)
  b = display.newImageRect("images/Spike.png", 37,80)
  b.x = display.contentWidth + 100
  b.y = math.random(2) == 1 and display.contentCenterY -75 or display.contentCenterY +40
  b.rotation = math.random(2) == 1 and 0 or 180
  b.name = 'block'
  physics.addBody( b, "static", physicsData:get("Spike"))
  blocks:insert(b)
end
```

EDIT:

```
function check( event )
   if b.rotation == 180 then
   b.y = math.random(2) == 1 and display.contentCenterY - 80 or display.contentCenterY + 30
   end
 end
```

Comment: Just check the variable for which way you are turning it "up or down" and move one of them further up/down accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the height of the object is H and the height of the spike is S (so the height of the 3 blocks is H - S), and you position them currently at Y, with Y increasing towards bottom of screen, and the object's origin is at the bottom of bottom-most block (opposite spike), and their default orientation is spike up, then:

- position the blocks that have spike up at Y + H; the tip of their spike will be at Y, and the bottom of the spike at Y + S.
- position the blocks that have spike down at Y + S, then rotate 180 deg. The top-most edge of the blocks will be at Y+S, which is what you want.

If any of the conditions in the first paragraph are different, you will have to make corresponding adjustments, but hopefully this shows how to figure it out.

**Update:**

Probably a better way is to shift the anchor point so it is in the center of the middle square. By default anchor is at 0.5, thus placing it between the 2nd and 3rd squares (assuming the square furthest from spike is "the first square"). Since your Block consists of 4 cells (3 squares and one spike), you could do this:

```
function createBlock(event)
  local H = 80
  local b = display.newImageRect("images/Spike.png", 37, H)
  b.x = display.contentWidth + 100 -- NOTE: weird, doesn't this put the obj off screen? 
  local cellH = H/4 -- assume all four cells in a Block have this height
  b.anchorY = 0.5 - 0.25/2 -- each cell is 0.25 of height, need half that, away from spike
  b.rotation = math.random(2) == 1 and 0 or 180 -- will rotate around the new anchorY
  local posY = display.contentCenterY - 75
  b.y = math.random(2) == 1 and posY or posY + 115
  b.name = 'block'
  physics.addBody( b, "static", physicsData:get("Spike"))
  blocks:insert(b)
end
```

Note that `b.anchorY` might have to be `b.anchorY = 0.5 + 0.25/2` depending on how you have created your image, but it should be either + or - 1/8.

Comment: Hi guys, not sure if I did this the most efficient way but after reading your replies I created a function which has a condition for whenever the object is flipped (180, spikes up) it increases its position slightly. Code added to question.

Comment: That's great, it works much more better now! Thanks for the help Schollii.                                                             ps: The objects were placed off screen so that they scroll in to play.